# Do a simple calculation in a hidden field (html form)

Tags: html, wordpress, forms

I have this really simple task that I just don't can't figure out.

I have a form field were the user can input an amount (eg. 125 or 125,89)

What I need is a hidden field that multiplies the inserted value with 100. (eg. 12500 or 12589).

I need the form for Wordpress site.

Any advice would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Use Javascript. If you have jQuery it's a one-liner: <script>$('#field1').change(function(){$('#field1').val($('#field2').val() * 100);});</script> Or you could(should) use PHP if possible.

Comment: if you are handling it with php then you dun need a hidden field

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="number" name="number" />
<input type="hidden" name="newNumber" id="newNumber" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#number').change(function(){
        var val = parseInt($(this).val());
        val = val * 100;
        $('#newNumber').val(val);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Calvin deClaisse-Walford but I cant get it working. I put the script in the header, but the newNumber field does not get the value inserted in the number field.

Comment: If you are putting the script in the header, it's trying to run before page load is complete and therefore won't find the #number element.  I'll edit the code to allow loading in the header.

Comment: Also, make sure you are loading jQuery BEFORE you run this function, otherwise you'll get an error.